# SwiftUI - Navigation title background becomes transparent when VStack is visible

Tags: swiftui

I'm running into an issue with the navigation title header in SwiftUI. It's a combination of a couple of things, as far as I can tell...

The main problem is that I'm trying to change the default background color of a view that contains a list. But when I use the tag `.background()`, the navigation title background becomes transparent. This only happens when there is a VStack on the view.

I have a simplify example code that shows the problem I'm facing:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showButton: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondView(showButton: showButton),
                    label: {
                        Text("Take me to second view")
                    })
                Toggle("VStack Visibile", isOn: $showButton)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible: Bool = false
    @State var showButton: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(0..<10) { _ in
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            if showButton {
                button
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("This is a title")
        .background(Color(.systemCyan))
    }
    
    var button: some View {
        Text("Something")
    }
}
```

Please see below the resulting problem:

[image]

Comment: Don't embed List inside a VStack, are you looking for a bottom overlay over the list?

Comment: Yes, I haven't thought about that. But the end goal is to have a bottom overlay. It is a single button right now, but it might change to a more complex menu in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues / Suggestions:

### ContentView

- Have the `NavigationStack` outside the `VStack`

### SecondView

- Don't embed List inside a `VStack`
- `List` is special and has special characteristics
- Don't initialise `@State` property from outside, pass a binding instead

## Code:

### ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showButton = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondView(showButton: $showButton),
                    label: {
                        Text("Take me to second view")
                    })
                Toggle("VStack Visibile", isOn: $showButton)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### SecondView

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible: Bool = false
    @Binding var showButton: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<100) { _ in
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            if showButton {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    button
                    Spacer()
                }
                //I have added transparency, you can make it opaque if you want
                .background(.cyan.opacity(0.8))
            }
        }
    }
    
    var button: some View {
        Text("Something")
    }
}
```

[image: Bottom Overlay]

Comment: Nice!! `.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom)` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you don't want your list go under nav bar.

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible: Bool = false
    @State var showButton: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(0..<10) { _ in
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .padding(.top, 1)
            if showButton {
                button
            }
        }
        .background(Color(.systemCyan))
        .navigationTitle("This is a title")
    }
    
    var button: some View {
        Text("Something")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see that this "fixes" the problem, although I don't even know why the padding changes the behavior... In any case, not the solution I was looking for. 

I could add `.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)`, and it produces the result you are mentioning, but it is not the default iOS behavior for a list.